Angular datepicker set date 1 day before actual date input
I have an angular form that uses reactive forms, i have this datepicker:
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
          <mat-label>Prossima scadenza</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="picker"
            [min]="minDate"
            formControlName="chosendate"
            (change)="datePickerChanged($event)"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matIconSuffix
            [for]="picker"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

And this is my ts:
form = new FormGroup({
    ...
    nextdeadline: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    ...
  });

datePickerChanged(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

the console log outputs the correct inserted date but when i submit the form the value that gets sent is 1 day before the selected date. Why is that? I already set MAT_DATE_LOCALE in the app.module.ts

That looks like a timezone issue.

What can I do about it? @MatthieuRiegler

This could be explained by the local timezone being East of the prime meridian, and the form submit is automatically converting from local time to GMT/UTC time (London time) which is behind.
For more context, it is a common problem across many languages and platforms to have dates that are off by 1 day, particularly for client-side development.  The root cause is typically caused by timezones. Each user is potentially in a different timezone, so storing local date/time information without timezone explicitly leads to ambiguous data.  A best practice for multi-timezone applications is to store time as UTC/GMT (London time) which can then be easily ordered and compared across the globe.  (Note, daylight savings time complicates matters more, but that's another discussion.)
One solution in this case is to reframe the "bug" as a feature.  It is valid to store time as a day behind the local time, because it may be a day behind in a universal time zone like GMT.  An alternative solution would be to configure the Angular Datepicker to use local timezones, which could be appropriate if your users are always and will always be in the same time zone.  See answer below:
How can I set up a specific timezone for angular material datepicker?

So, how do you suggest I solve this? @user23356021
